# Generate RSAv2 key in OpenSSH format in Windows

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

I have to generate a key, RSA v2 in OpenSSH format. I am a bit confused. I am trying to generate it using Putty Key Generator. There I see an option SSH2-RSA, SSH1-RSA. So is SSH2-RSA the RSA2 key or it means something else. Also is this key in the OpenSSH format. I see that there is a conversion tab with 2 options:
 export OpenSSh Key and export ssh.com key. So I am not sure if the keys I have generated are in OpenSSH format.

Regards
Ankur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have version 0.65 - dated 20150725 - of PuTTY installed : the maintainer is pretty up-to-date with standards, so the key generated will be also.

The `puttygen` tool will create a private key that you can save in "PuTTY" format (using the `Save private key` button), "OpenSSH" or "ssh.com" format using the according option in the `Conversions` menu.

Since the public key part is not encrypted and is only text-based, the format is irrelevant.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks a ton ionrelex. So the SSH2 here stands for RSA v2 right?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia I looked around about this and didn't find any concrete response, but according to this [link](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt) giving information about RSA revision 2.0 and dating back October 1998, I'm pretty sure the `puttygen` tool can't generate a key at a lower version.

Answer (score 2):

SSH-1 RSA means an RSA key for SSH version 1 (SSHv1)

SSH-2 RSA means an RSA key for SSH version 2 (SSHv2)

SSHv1 is fundamentally broken and should not be used.

http://www.employees.org/~satch/ssh/faq/ssh-faq-1.html

RSA works differently in SSHv1 vs. SSHv2 but I'm not aware of anything known as RSAv2.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/what-is-the-difference-between-rsa1-rsa-in-regards-to-ssh-also-when-is-the-fi

I suspect all you want is a standard RSA key for SSHv2 in OpenSSH format which case you want to select the `SSH-2 RSA` option in PuttyGen then `Conversion => Export OpenSSH key`. Nobody should be using SSHv1 anymore without good reason.